# Error while creating new nodejs project in Netbeans

Tags: node.js, express, netbeans

I have installed express globally and also ran `npm update -g` and I can create express app using terminal without problems. But when I create a new nodejs project in Netbeans 8.2 I get these errors :

```
module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/express:10:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Can someone help me integrate Expressjs properly with netbeans please? Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]
I figured there is something wrong in the Node path in Netbeans. Can someone tell me what do I add here for Ubuntu :[image]

Comment: Try `npm install` from project directory.

Comment: @ErrHunter Thnx for the reply. Ive done that but the problem is - I'm not getting the routes, views folder and the public folder is empty.

Comment: @ErrHunter I've updated my question a bit..if you could help i'd appreciate it. thx

Comment: What is output of `which node` from terminal ?

Comment: /home/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin/node

Comment: Now paste that path as Node Path

Comment: I got this error after "Node.js: Missing node.js sources"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138897/discussion-between-nochet-imchen-and-err-hunter).